# move_uploaded_file not working, no extension

Tags: php

I am trying to upload images to a web server in my php script. The images are uploaded via a HTML form.
The images uploaded to the server have no file extensions and are therefore saved as text files. However on opening them on the server, I can see the images.

**Here's an excerpt of my php script.**

```
$image1 = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
$filepath1 = "./images/";
$filepath1 = $filepath1 . basename($image1);

move_uploaded_file($image1, $filepath1);
```

**Here's a snippet of the server file manager.**

[image]

Comment: You're using the temp file filename instead of the uploaded filename in saving your image that's why you're uploaded image has no extension. Use `$_FILES['image1']['name']` as your destination file rather than `$_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the name attribute of image1.

You can try do this:

```
$tmp_path = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
$file_path = "./images/";

$new_path = $file_path . $_FILES['image1']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($tmp_path, $new_path);

var_dump($_FILES['image1']);
```